# How to save a CSV file that adds double quotes to special characters that enables easy importing?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, csv

When I was importing a CSV file to MySql Workbench that had special characters like comma, brackets, etc., few rows that contained data containing special characters were getting missed (, )) etc).

Therefore, my question is, how to save a CSV file that adds double quotes to special characters that enables easy importing?

Comment: This isn't a database question (you'll probably want to try StackOverflow), but the answer will depend on how you're saving your CSV files. What generates them?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Maybe you could go to dbfiddle.uk and give us a few typical lines of your file. I fail to see what's so "special" about brackets  - as for double quotes, files are frequently "enclosed by double quotes" to cope with fields which themselves contain commas! Otherwise, there are a host of *nix tools to help you, for example `sed` & `awk` or their Windows equivalents. Without seeing the data, it's difficult to be of any assistance.

Comment: Importing using Workbench == (1) MySQL (2) LOAD DATA. Hence study https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html and use according `FIELDS ESCAPED BY 'char'` at both CSV creating and importing.

Comment: I have created the CSV file through Excel and LibreOffice. The special characters in the field values are causing the issue so wanted to know what's the best practice to handle those. I read in multiple Q&As that adding double quotes is the best way but how to automate that while exporting CSVs through Excel / LibreOffice or by other means.

Answer (score 0):

I had already answered a similar answer in this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066953/remove-special-characters-from-a-database-field

Anyway I am repeating; It is easy to use regular expression in any editor
(gedit, LibreOffice, VS Code, netbeans ) any would do.
Just press replace command button usually it is Ctrl+R

Then in the search

```
[^\x20-\x7E]
```

and nothing the replace (or maybe a space) and press replace all.
That all